# Rewrite only working for first use

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On GoDaddy Linux hosting, really would like to get this mod rewrite working, but having a strange problem. Very simple code looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
rewriteengine on
RewriteBase /

## clean URLs
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/.]+)/?$ blog.php?title=$1 [L]
```

then as a test I went to `blog.php?title=testing` it did as it was supposed to and rewrote the URL to `blog/testing`. But then when I went to `blog.php?title=test` or `blog.php?title=new` it did not rewrite the URL, so i tried going to `blog/test` and `blog/new` and it gave me a 404 error. I thought something broke. So i went back to `blog.php?title=testing` and everything worked again. So it only worked for the first URL I entered.

Also I have this domain set up in a folder under root. so root is `example.com` but this site is `example.com/something` then GoDaddy turns that into `something.com`.

I want clean URLs, I still want the php to be able to use `$_GET` on the querystring, however I want the nice seo URL like `example.com/blog/title`

Comment: Do you want the url example.com/blog/test/ to display the content at blog.php?title=test like your rewriterule implies, and also rewrite blog.php?title=test to example.com/blog/test/?

Comment: @miah yes that is the plan

Comment: can you edit your question to include what you are using to do the rewrite from  blog.php?title=test to example.com/blog/test/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rule should redirect your php file to the pretty URL second rule should internally redirect the pretty URL to the old one internally so its not visible to the user:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect /blog.php?title=anything to /blog/anything
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+blog\.php\?title=([^\s&]+)&? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /blog/%1? [R=302,L]

# Internally forward /blog/anything to /blog.php?title=anything
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^blog/([\w-]+)/?$ /blog.php?title=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, fixed my problem, but I am not very good with regex. Say I use php's url_encode to create the query string. So it is like a+new+article. How would I allow the plus sign in .htaccess, because as of now, when a plus sign is used it goes to a 404

Comment: At the last RewriteRule, here is where we capture the title `([\w-]+)` to allow the plus sign you would add it inside the squared brackets `([\w-+]+)`. The `\w` means any alphanumeric which also includes underscore, then `-` dash then `+` plus sign and the `+` right outside of it means any amount.